# Quartz scheduler Database Connection issue with Websphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler, websphere-8

Our Quartz application works on Websphere Application Server 8.5. We have been encountering the following issue frequently and scheduler is not working until it is restarted.

`2014-01-07 21:28:31,363 [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-XXXX00411388763379255_ClusterManager] ERROR org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - ClusterManager: Error managing cluster: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'springNonTxDataSource.quartzScheduler': java.sql.SQLException: Failed preTestConnection. Pool requests blocked for jdbc/xxx_xxxx until the test connection thread is successful.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'springNonTxDataSource.quartzScheduler': java.sql.SQLException: Failed preTestConnection. Pool requests blocked for jdbc/xxx_xxxx until the test connection thread is successful. [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Failed preTestConnection. Pool requests blocked for jdbc/xxx_xxxx until the test connection thread is successful.]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:165)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3183)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3820)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3856)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed preTestConnection. Pool requests blocked for jdbc/xxx_xxxx until the test connection thread is successful.
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1697)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:661)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:611)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore$2.getConnection(LocalDataSourceJobStore.java:125)
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:109)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:162)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Failed preTestConnection. Pool requests blocked for jdbc/xxx_xxxx until the test connection thread is successful.
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3004)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2643)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1545)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1028)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:644)
    ... 7 more
2014-01-07 21:36:33,540 [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-XXXXX00411388763379255_MisfireHandler] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Handling 9 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
2014-01-07 21:41:33,552 [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-XXXXX00411388763379255_MisfireHandler] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Handling 1 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
2014-01-07 21:46:33,565 [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-XXXXX00411388763379255_MisfireHandler] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Handling 1 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
2014-01-07 21:51:33,612 [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-XXXXX00411388763379255_MisfireHandler] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Handling 6 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
2014-01-07 21:56:33,624 [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-XXXXX00411388763379255_MisfireHandler] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Handling 3 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.`

I thought there is some bug in Websphere App server 8.5 as per below URL:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI05749

But it is mentioned only for Websphere application server Liberty core.

Quartz version 1.8.3 and WAS 8.5

Ideas are appreciable.

Thanks,
Chaatna

Comment: Out of curiosity, Quartz 2.x is out since some time, why are you using 1.x? Is that a requirement for your application?

Comment: Application was developed long time back and now they may not accept to change Quartz version.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't have an answer for your question, but it seems that the scheduler isn't able to get a connection to the database. Once or twice I got similar errors because the connection pool got all the available connections to the database and wasn't able to obtain anymore, resulting in a pending application. You could try to increase the maximum allowed connections on the database side, it may be worth a try.

Comment: same with me even with version 2.2.1

Comment: We use tomcat8,Spring4 and quartz 2.2.1, It is happening in one node configuration in our environements, our dev and integration have one node and we get this exception there but at test environment which has two nodes didn't get this exception.